# CakePHP multiple tables in single model with same structure and suffix

Tags: php, database, cakephp, model

I have somewhat of a unique situation.  In a database, I have multiple tables, all with the same structure and suffix.  What I'd like to do is use one model for all of these tables, I'd like to tell Cake to load all tables into a model that have the suffix of `_some_suffix`.  These tables are read only, I'm using them for a match case with user registration and they have the exact same structure, they are just localized into different tables. Any suggestions?

Comment: Sounds either unnecessarily complex, or too vague. How many tables? what do you want to achieve by having "multiple tables in single model" (a model will only represent _one_ table at any given moment), what does "to load all tables into a model" mean - do you mean a UNION sql query?

Comment: I am not entirely sure how Cake handles this, but I assume "just fine": What about making a Model and Child Models? So let's say you have `CompareOne extends Compare` and `CompareTwo extends Compare`. Where `CompareX` matches the table? Now you can put the code in your `Compare` model which acts like some sort of a `AppModel` but on a lower level. Seems a bit vague, but might help you in some way? I'm not sure either :) Sounds like an interesting question though.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can a model have multiple tables in CakePHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/713736/can-a-model-have-multiple-tables-in-cakephp)