# Cakephp Is there a way make a Model that is based on another Model?

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-2.0

I'm trying to join two tables that are in two different databases. These databases don't necessarily have to be the same. So i'm trying to see if I can make a model off of one model and another model off the other model and join the two derived models. Or if there is a way that you know how to join two models of different databases that'd be great too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible for a Model to use two Tables/Databases

> A model is generally an access point to the database, and more specifically, to a certain table in the database. By default, each model uses the table who's name is plural of its own, i.e. a 'User' model uses the 'users' table.

[Source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/713736/can-a-model-have-multiple-tables-in-cakephp)

The second Answer says it is possible, but I don't think it will work the way you want it.

[However it is possible for a Model to use a different Database](http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/mithesh/2008/09/02/talking-to-multiple-databases-from-single-cakephp-application).

You can then create a relationship to link them.

Comment: Yes I would like to relate two tables that are in different databases. So when I use ->find I'll be able to join the tables together. Even though they're from different databases.

Comment: You can do this like I told you, create the two models and create a relationship between them (hasOne/hasMany/belongsTo).
Then you can make a find for model 1 or model 2 and you will get the related data from the other model.

Answer (score 0):

It could be achieved with [useDbConfig](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/model-attributes.html#usedbconfig) easily (just tested).
Another way is to use DB view.

Comment: Yes, I would like to have one model based off of one table in one database. Then have another model based off a different table in a different database. Then, combine these two models based off a find query.